# dbeaver session manager sql length limit problem with execution plan

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

i have an active session in postgresqldb and im monitoring this session by a dbeaver. Since the length of the sql more han 1000 characters, session manager does not show all sql and active execution plan. Is there a limit options or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to change the size for [track_activity_query_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html#GUC-TRACK-ACTIVITY-QUERY-SIZE). You could do this on server level in the configuration file, on user level or connection level.

Comment: Thank you. this is the solution :)